# Empty if-block not optimized away?

Tags: c#, optimization, jit, cil

Will the following empty if-block be optimized away?

```cs
public class C 
{
    private bool foo = false;
    
    public void M() 
    {
        if(foo) {}
    }
}
```

SharpLab (master 5 Dec 2020, Release) indicates that the compiler does not optimize the if-block away:

```
.method public hidebysig instance void M () cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldfld bool C::foo
    IL_0006: pop
    IL_0007: ret
}
```

Should the compiler not be able to see that `ldfld` followed by `pop` has no effect and the three instructions (`ldarg.0` too) do not need to be emitted?

I cannot think of possible side effects that would occur when not emitting `ldfld` (as there could be when calling a method inside the if-block).

---

Further, the JIT ASM that SharpLab generates also does not seem to optimize the empty if-block away:

```
C.M()
    L0000: movzx eax, byte ptr [ecx+4]
    L0004: ret
```

---

Am I right in thinking that the JIT will still optimize the empty if-block away?

- If so, could you please explain why the compiler cannot do that?
- If not, why does it not?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you building this target as release or debug? I think in debug certain optimizations my not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Further, the JIT ASM that SharpLab generates also does not seem to optimize the empty if-block away:
>
> ```
> C.M()
>     L0000: movzx eax, byte ptr [ecx+4]
>     L0004: ret
> ```

The actual `if` block has been optimized away, if it existed it would have looked comparable to this:

```
C.M()
    L0000: movzx eax, byte ptr [ecx+4]
    L0004: test eax, eax
    L0006: je short L0008
    L0008: ret
```

But that did not happen, the JIT-compiler apparently figured out that this would not be useful.

Only the load of the boolean field still exists.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know assembly well and was too focused on the JIT ASM not only being `ret`, so I jumped to a wrong conclusion... however, do you know why the load of the boolean field still exists? What about your (now edited) point of the load existing so that `null` cannot be passed to the method?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow a dummy load gets inserted into the caller if necessary (for example [like this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiAhgZwLYB8ACAmAjAWAChMBmAAhzIGEyBvIsxiqMgWQAoAhRAJzOF4BKOgyZiBPAHQAxAPaz2ggNyjGAX1VlNlbn3qExY0szJyFw2hoNMraoA==) where `mov eax, [rdx]` does nothing besides trigger the NRE), so that wouldn't be it after all. Boring as it is, I have to put it down to the JIT compiler being a bit dumb.

Comment: Optimizing the load away could lead to observable changes in behaviour. If you use `call` instead of `callvirt` on the method and pass `null` as `this`, the original code would still throw *NullReferenceException* from the load, while without it the method would return normally. Might be interesting to see if `static` fields behave the same way.

Comment: @IllidanS4supportsMonica that was a hypothesis originally, but a dummy load is inserted into the caller, so if `this` is `null` then the method is never even called and it doesn't need to crash itself

Comment: I guess the compiler is that dumb then.